# How to control processing of File connector in MULESOFT

Tags: java, mule

I am using ANYPOINT STUDIO 6.1.0 and for a project we need to set an input endpoint for incoming files from a third party server. The concern is that as soon as the file is put in the folder the processing starts asynchronously.

1. Can we control the file processing in any way?
2. How can we make a flow wait for an async process/thread to complete?

Answer (score 1):

use 'File Age' property in file connector. You can specify time in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Configure receiver threading profile and set doThreading=false so that it can process synchronously.

```
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File">
<receiver-threading-profile doThreading="false"/>
</file:connector>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize mule requester module.